# Notification Manager creates only one notification channel but i need to create three channels

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, notificationmanager, notification-channel

in my application, i have created 3 notification channels (**Follow**, **Comment**, **Like**) to receive notifications from `Firebase Cloud Messaging`.

When i run app and go to **Settings > Apps > My App > App Notifications** , I found it show only one notification channel (ex. Follow channel) and other two channels are't be shown ...

But when i receive notification from *Comment channel* for example, it updates current channel with *Comment channel* and when i receive notification from *Like channel*, it updates current channel with Like channel and so on..

so why it doesn't show three channels as separated channels  at same time ?!

Here is `Code I work with`:

```
public class MyFireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    String title, content, type;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


        title = remoteMessage.getData().get("Notif_Title");
        content= remoteMessage.getData().get("Notif_Content");
        type = remoteMessage.getData().get("Type");
        

        if (type.equals("Follow")) {

            NotificationManager manager1 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         
            Intent result = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, result, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(postContent)
                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                  
            //to work on android 8 and high..
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                builder.setChannelId("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME");
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);

                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                        "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
                        "Follow",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

                manager1.createNotificationChannel(channel);


            }

            manager1.notify(0, builder.build());

        } else if (type.equals("Comment")) {

            NotificationManager manager2 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Intent result = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, result, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

             NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(content)
                    .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                  
  //to work on android 8 and high..
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                builder.setChannelId("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME");
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);

                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                        "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
                        "Comment",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

                manager3.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                }

            manager3.notify(1, builder.build());


        } else if (type.equals("Like")) {
            Intent result = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
         
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 2, result, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationManager manager3 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(title)) 
                        .setContentText(content)
                        .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                     

                //to work on android 8 and high..
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                    builder.setChannelId("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME");
                    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);

                    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                            "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
                            "Like",
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

                    manager3.createNotificationChannel(channel);

                }

                manager3.notify(2, builder.build());

            }
    }
}
```

Can Anyone help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to solve it ...
You should change this code

```
     builder.setChannelId("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME");
     builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```

Into specific `channel id` to each one  like :

```
    builder.setChannelId("com.myapp.first_notification");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
```